# Java Accept/decline window popup

Tags: java, dialog, popup, window

I have been searching on the internet for a few hours now and I am not able to find what I am looking for, So I am making a question here instead.

Basically my issue is that when I click a button I want a new window to popup, the window should have a decline / accept button on it and if the user pushes the Decline button x = 0, and if the user pushes Accept x = 1.

I just want it to open a new basic window with ONLY those 2 options.

Thanks a lot :)

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == JButton){
      // Open window (Accept/decline offer)
      // If "Accept" x = 1;
      // else x = 0;
    }
} //end actionPerformed()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Hope it helps.